# Create data.table with repeating set of numbers

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create a data table with two columns X and Y with X = 11 to 20 and Y = 1 to 5. The resulting data table must have 50 rows with X, Y values of all possible combinations. How do I do this? I tried the code below but it does not work. Thanks

```
dt <- data.table[a = rep(11:20,each = 5), b = rep(1:5,times = 10)]
```

Comment: Tell us what "does not work" means.

Comment: For "all possible combinations" you can also inspect `expang.grid` from base R

Comment: You could use `CJ(11:20, 1:5)`, from your code, the `[` should be `(`, or `]` with `)`

Comment: You should use `()` not `[]` with the `data.table` function. I agree with akrun and docendo's suggestions (`expand.grid` and `CJ`).

Answer (score 4):

Does this solve your problem?

```
result = expand.grid(X = 11:20, Y = 1:5)
```

Answer (score 4):

are you looking for something like this

```
CJ(X=11:20, Y=1:5)
```